# C# How to raise an event to start timer from a class other than the main form?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, timer, void

In my main Form1, I have

```
int duration = 5;
public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    duration--;
    if (duration == 0)
    {
       timer1.Stop();
       MessageBox.Show("timesup");
    }
}
```

Elsewhere, (specifically the class I use for my UDP listener), I run an event to reference changes to the form

```
private MyProject.Form1 _form { get; set; }
public UDPListener(TapeReader.Form1 form)
{
     _form = form;
}
```

Then I would try to call it when the incoming data meets my criteria

```
if (numberSize>paramSize)
{
    if (_form.listBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
          _form.listBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
          {
              //Below is where I would like the timer to start
              _form.timer1.Start();   
              //This won't work as I need the timer1_Tick from the main. How can I run this from a different class other than the main form?
          });
    }
}
```

Like the other components of my form, I can reference it fine with `_form` but timer1_Tick is a method (void). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand why you need `timer1_Tick` in that other method?

Comment: Also, why are you calling `timer1.Start();` _inside_ the timer tick handler?

Comment: Also, `timer1.Enabled = true;` and `timer1.Start();` is the same thing.

Comment: Ooops, timer1.Start(); isn't supposed to be in the tick handler. I fixed that thx. Some code got put out of place when I copied and pasted it.

Comment: I'm trying to raise an event with the Timer.Tick Event. I'd like it to countdown before it terminates the event. If you have alternatives, I'd be happy to try them out. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Figured a solution. I just used this tutorial to help me https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx

In my other class, I have:

```
 _form.timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
```

and I reference it to

```
int duration = 5;
    private void TimerEventProcessor(object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        duration--;
        if(duration==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("timesup");

        }
    }
```